# Passing a String in Another Intent not working

Tags: android, android-intent, null, nullpointerexception

i have a problem. I need to pass a String into another Android intent and i get this error. I have done this passing before. No idea why it isnt working now. this is what i get.

```
> 10-29 15:17:03.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1641): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 10-29 15:17:03.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.projectx/com.example.projectx.InfoActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException 10-29 15:17:03.254:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1641):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
> 10-29 15:17:03.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
> 10-29 15:17:03.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 10-29
> 15:17:03.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
> 10-29 15:17:03.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-29
> 15:17:03.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-29 15:17:03.254:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1641):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 10-29
> 15:17:03.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-29
> 15:17:03.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 10-29 15:17:03.254:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1641):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
> 10-29 15:17:03.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 10-29
> 15:17:03.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-29 15:17:03.254:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1641): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> 10-29 15:17:03.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):   at
> com.example.projectx.InfoActivity.onCreate(InfoActivity.java:31) 10-29
> 15:17:03.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 10-29
> 15:17:03.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):     at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
> 10-29 15:17:03.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
> 10-29 15:17:03.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1641):   ... 11 more 10-29
> 15:17:08.494: I/Process(1641): Sending signal. PID: 1641 SIG: 9
```

And these are my two Activity classes

Main Activity:

```
 package com.example.projectx;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout mainlayout;
    private LinearLayout list_of_countries;
    private ScrollView scroll;
    private EditText search;
    private View countryline;
    private Button searchButton;
    private ArrayList<JSONObject> countriesJSON;
    private HashMap<String,JSONObject> countriesINFO;
    private String name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); 
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        scroll=new ScrollView(this);
        mainlayout=new LinearLayout(this);
        list_of_countries =new LinearLayout(this);
        search=new EditText(this);
        searchButton=new Button(this);
        countriesINFO=new HashMap<String, JSONObject>();
        String jsoncountries=readData("http://api.worldbank.org/countries?per_page=256&format=json");
        countriesJSON=getCountriesJSON(jsoncountries);
        CreateGUI();
        setContentView(mainlayout);
    }

    public void CreateGUI()

    {

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mainlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        mainlayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        search.setHint("Search...");
        mainlayout.addView(search);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        list_of_countries.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        list_of_countries.setLayoutParams(params2);
        for(int i=0; i<countriesJSON.size();i++)
         {
             try {

                 if (countriesJSON.get(i).getString("capitalCity").equals("")) { }

                 else {

                     name = countriesJSON.get(i).getString("name");
                     countriesINFO.put(name, countriesJSON.get(i));
                     countryline= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.country_line, list_of_countries, false);
                     list_of_countries.addView(countryline);
                     TextView country= (TextView)countryline.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                     country.setTextSize(26.0f);
                     country.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                     country.setText(name);
                     country.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            //intent.putExtra("data", countriesINFO);
                            startIntent();
                    }

                    });


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

         }
        // search.setText(countriesINFO.size()+"");
         scroll.addView(list_of_countries);
         mainlayout.addView(scroll);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /*A method which starts the InfoActivity and put the HashMap and the name of the country*/
    public void startIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", name);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    /*END*/

    /**A METHOD TO GET ALL JSON OBJECTS OF ALL COUNTRIES*/
    public ArrayList<JSONObject> getCountriesJSON(String json) {

        ArrayList<JSONObject> countriesJSON=new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

        try {
            JSONArray array=new JSONArray(json);
            JSONArray countries=array.getJSONArray(1);
            for (int i=0;i<countries.length();i++) {
                countriesJSON.add(countries.getJSONObject(i));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return countriesJSON;
    }
    /*END OF THAT METHOD*/




    /**READ DATA METHOD*/
     public String readData(String url) {

         // Create download objects
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

        try {
        // Execute response and create input stream
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (responseCode == 200) {

            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            // Build string from input stream
            String readLine = reader.readLine();
            while (readLine != null) {
                content.append(readLine);
                readLine = reader.readLine();
            }
        } else {
            Log.w("DATA RETRIEVAL","Unable to read data. HTTP response code = " + responseCode);
            content = null;
        }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e("readData","ClientProtocolException:\n"+e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("readData","IOException:\n+e.getMessage()");
        }

        // return data
        if (content==null) {
        return(null);
        } else {
        return(content.toString());
        }

     }
    /*END OF READ DATA METHOD*/


}
```

Info Activity:

```
package com.example.projectx;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InfoActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView country;
    private HashMap<String,JSONObject> countriesINFO;
    private String countryNAME;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        country=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        //countryNAME=intent.getStringExtra("name");
        /*if (intent.getExtras().size()==1) {
        /*countriesINFO= (HashMap<String, JSONObject>) intent.getSerializableExtra("data");*/
        /*country.setText("evala"); } */
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        countryNAME = extras.getString("name");
        country.setText(extras.size());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.info, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you remove those > and reformat the output ?

Comment: typical case of `findViewById` before `setContentView`

Answer (score 4):

I think you are trying to access a textview before setting the content view of your activity.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);
```

Must be before you access the textview.